Sentry logging missing HTTP server-side metadata for SvelteKit
I have a Sentry integration with SvelteKit hooks.server.js.
Errors are correctly logged in Sentry, but HTTP request metadata like user agent, request URL, IP addresses and such are missing, as seen in the issue screenshot below. These are quite important to troubleshoot many issues.

I am using the following hooks.server.js integration code (based on Sentry's example):
import { sequence } from '@sveltejs/kit/hooks';
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/sveltekit';
import { dev } from '$app/environment';
import { env } from '$env/dynamic/private';

if(!dev) {
  Sentry.init({
    dsn: env.SENTRY_DSN,
    environment: dev ? "dev" : "production",
    // https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/8925#issue-1876274074
    ignoreErrors: [
      "TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module",
      "Load failed",
      "TypeError: Load failed",
      "TypeError: Failed to fetch",
      "Failed to fetch",
      "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource",
      "TypeError: Importing a module script failed",
      "TypeError: error loading dynamically imported module",
      "RollupError: Expected unicode escape"
    ],  
  });
}

export const handleError = Sentry.handleErrorWithSentry((async ({ error }) => {  
    const eventId = Sentry.lastEventId();
    if (eventId) {
        return { message: 'Internal Server Error', eventId };
    }
}));


// prettier-ignore
let handle;

if(!dev) {
  handle = sequence(
    Sentry.sentryHandle(),
    # ... rest
  );  
} else {
  handle =   handle = sequence(
    # ... rest
  );  
}


export default handle;



What could be the cause that SvelteKit integration for Sentry does not correctly log these?


Sentry SvelteKit SDK maintainer here!
Your setup looks correct but Http request data extraction was missing in the SvelteKit SDK.We added the feature recently to the sentryHandle request handler. Once version 8.6.0 is released, you should be getting http request data like url, method and headers.

Hi can you try updating your init to include sendDefaultPII ?
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/sveltekit";

Sentry.init({
  dsn: YOUR_DSN,
  integrations: [Sentry.httpClientIntegration()]
  ....
  sendDefaultPii: true,
});

See the docs here

It does not seem to help.

have you tried testing with different browsers?

This is the server-side capture, so it does not matter what browser you use, you should still get HTTP headers.
